# Jar not found error while while trying to deploy SCDF Stream

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I registered the sink first as follows:

```
app register --name mysink --type sink --uri file:///Users/swatikaushik/Downloads/kafkaStreamDemo/target/kafkaStreamDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Then I created a stream

```
stream create --definition “:myKafkaTopic > mysink" --name myStreamName --deploy
```

I got the error

```
Command failed org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.DataFlowClientException: File 
/Users/swatikaushik/Downloads/kafkaStreamDemo/target/kafkaStreamDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar must exist
```

While the jar exists!!

Comment: Could you please include full stack trace? Also can you check permissions on the JAR file you're trying to deploy?

Answer (score 1):

I'v followed the maven local repository mounting approach, using the docker compose, hope this helps:

Maven:

```
mvn clean install
```

Setup your environment variables:

```
$Env:DATAFLOW_VERSION="2.5.1.RELEASE"
$Env:SKIPPER_VERSION="2.4.1.RELEASE"
$Env:HOST_MOUNT_PATH="C:\Users\yourUserName\.m2"
$Env:DOCKER_MOUNT_PATH="/root/.m2/"
```

Restart/start the containers:

```
docker-compose down 
docker-compose up
```

Register your apps:

```
app register --type sink--name mysink --uri maven://groupId:artifactId:version
```

[Register Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-dataflow-register-apps.html)

Answer (score 0):

File permission is one thing - please double check as advised.

A few other ideas:

1) Run `app info sink:mysink`. If the JAR is actually available, it should return with a list of Boot/Whitelisted properties of the Application.

2) Run the Jar standalone. Make sure it actually starts via `java -jar....`.

3) The stream definition appear to include a special character (`“:myKafkaTopic > mysink"` instead of `":myKafkaTopic > mysink"` - notice the `“` character); it would fail in the Shell, but it looks like you were able to deploy it. A full stacktrace would help.

Answer (score 0):

We just had the same error as described above.
We had mounted the folder of the jar files to the skipper.

The solution was, that we had to mount the jars to the data-flow server docker container as well.

Skipper is deploying it, but dataflow server registers it.