# unable to register jars from local repository as files

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm having the exact same problem as described here:

[Jar not found error while while trying to deploy SCDF Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49935235/jar-not-found-error-while-while-trying-to-deploy-scdf-stream)

app info source:http-transformer says

```
Application info is not available for source:http-transformer
```

This is not a standalone jar but the one downloaded from the git repo in https://spring.io/blog/2019/01/09/composed-function-support-in-spring-cloud-data-flow

I see it in my .m2 directory

I'm trying to register it with:

```
app register --type source --uri file:///Users/mark.juszczec/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/http-transformer/2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/http-transformer-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar http-transformer
```

and

```
app register --type source --uri file:///Users/mark.juszczec/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/http-transformer/2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/http-transformer-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar --name http-transformer
```

I'm at a complete loss.

As requested, here is the output from:

```
java -jar http-transformer-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar


   .   ____          _            __ _ _
  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
 ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.1.RELEASE)

 2019-01-14 07:40:44.281  INFO 2117 --- [           main] .c.s.a.h.s.r.HttpSourceRabbitApplication : Starting HttpSourceRabbitApplication v2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT on akr01mjuszczec.local with PID 2117 (/Users/mark.juszczec/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/http-transformer/2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/http-transformer-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar started by mark.juszczec in /Users/mark.juszczec)
 2019-01-14 07:40:44.292  INFO 2117 --- [           main] .c.s.a.h.s.r.HttpSourceRabbitApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
 2019-01-14 07:40:46.675  INFO 2117 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
 2019-01-14 07:40:46.683  INFO 2117 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
 2019-01-14 07:40:46.691  INFO 2117 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
 2019-01-14 07:40:46.747  INFO 2117 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1e3b1646] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
 2019-01-14 07:40:46.773  INFO 2117 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fc671d17] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
 2019-01-14 07:40:46.815  INFO 2117 --- [           main] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
 2019-01-14 07:40:46.885  INFO 2117 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationDisposableAutoCreatedBeans' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.Disposables] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
 2019-01-14 07:40:46.912  INFO 2117 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c2c11347] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
 2019-01-14 07:40:46.922  INFO 2117 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration$IntegrationJmxConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration$IntegrationJmxConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9e531e67] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
 2019-01-14 07:40:46.942  INFO 2117 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d73ac734] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
 2019-01-14 07:40:46.953  INFO 2117 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'mbeanServer' of type [com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
 2019-01-14 07:40:47.903  INFO 2117 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
 2019-01-14 07:40:47.960  INFO 2117 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
 2019-01-14 07:40:47.960  INFO 2117 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.13
 2019-01-14 07:40:47.986  INFO 2117 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/mark.juszczec/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
 2019-01-14 07:40:48.156  INFO 2117 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
 2019-01-14 07:40:48.156  INFO 2117 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3705 ms
 2019-01-14 07:40:48.964  INFO 2117 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
 2019-01-14 07:40:50.224  INFO 2117 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
 2019-01-14 07:40:51.140  INFO 2117 --- [           main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

 Using generated security password: <redacted>

 2019-01-14 07:40:51.362  INFO 2117 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/**'], []
 2019-01-14 07:40:51.447  INFO 2117 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5d9b7a8a, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@2d96543c, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@3ed242a4, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@3e30646a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@69653e16, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@5ef6ae06, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@6b8d96d9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@1e8ce150, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@1cdc4c27, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7d64e326, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@68be8808, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@604f2bd2, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@614df0a4, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@63a270c9, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@2dca0d64]
 2019-01-14 07:40:51.598  INFO 2117 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
 2019-01-14 07:40:51.975  INFO 2117 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel nullChannel
 2019-01-14 07:40:52.012  INFO 2117 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel errorChannel
 2019-01-14 07:40:52.116  INFO 2117 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel output
 2019-01-14 07:40:52.192  INFO 2117 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageHandler errorLogger
 2019-01-14 07:40:52.231  INFO 2117 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageSource httpSourceString
 2019-01-14 07:40:52.249  INFO 2117 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageSource httpSourceBytes
 2019-01-14 07:40:52.270  INFO 2117 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
 2019-01-14 07:40:52.270  INFO 2117 --- [           main] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
 2019-01-14 07:40:52.271  INFO 2117 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
 2019-01-14 07:40:52.572  INFO 2117 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
 2019-01-14 07:40:52.692  INFO 2117 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#9cb8225:0/SimpleConnection@201b6b6f [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 50519]
 2019-01-14 07:40:52.746  INFO 2117 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : Channel 'application.output' has 1 subscriber(s).
 2019-01-14 07:40:52.749  INFO 2117 --- [           main] .h.i.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway : started httpSourceString
 2019-01-14 07:40:52.750  INFO 2117 --- [           main] .h.i.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway : started httpSourceBytes
 2019-01-14 07:40:52.836  INFO 2117 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
 2019-01-14 07:40:52.839  INFO 2117 --- [           main] .c.s.a.h.s.r.HttpSourceRabbitApplication : Started HttpSourceRabbitApplication in 9.448 seconds (JVM running for 10.214)
```

Comment: When you run `app info` and it fails, there should be an error in server logs. Could you add that to question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely to happen if you have corrupt JAR. I tried to run through the sample again and I could register the app fine.

Can you confirm if you can run this fine:

```
java -jar /Users/mark.juszczec/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/http-transformer/2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/http-transformer-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

This will give us an idea if your JAR is fine.

Comment: i've attached the requested output as an edit to the original post

Comment: Thanks! When you get `Application info is not available for source:http-transformer`, do you see any stacktrace at the SCDF server side? Also, please confirm the following: java version, OS of your environment and any other hints to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be

```
app register --type source --uri file:///Users/mark.juszczec/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/http-transformer/2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/http-transformer-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar --name http-transformer?
```

It appears you're missing `--name`

Comment: i've found --name to be optional.  but i get the same error if i specify it

Answer (score 0):

i've abandoned this route. i've figured out how to create a docker image that i'm able to deploy via app register --uri ... but thank you for all the help